# Link and redirect a list entry in jinja2 to a route when picture is clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to have an image redirect to a page with a userid (user) that is in a list with position x[1].
Can't I use {{ x[1] }} to pass the user?

```
  <a href="{{ url_for('getprofile'), user= {{ x[1] }})">
            <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{x[0]}}" >
            </a>
```

I get the error:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('getprofile'), user= {{ x[1] }})">

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable without extra `{{ }}`.

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('getprofile', user=x[1]) }}">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ x[0] }}">
</a>
```